# Некорректно отображается Webview приложение на смартфонах Xiaomi

Tags: android, android-webview

Всем доброго дня, столкнулся с проблемой отображения обычного webview приложения, созданного в Andtoid Studio.
На смартфонах Xiaomi, в зависимости от темы темной/светлой, перерисовывается отображаемый в webview сайт. При это на эмуляторе Pixel 5 такой проблемы нет, как и на моем Samsung Note 10. С помощью кода:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

принудительно убрал возможность смены темы на темную в приложении, однако и при этом Xiaomi перекрашивает сайт в темный тона, как будто делает инверсию цветов. При этом некорректно отображаются картинки на сайте.
[image: Правильный вариант отображения сайта в Webview (при светлой теме на телефоне)]

Правильный вариант отображения сайта в Webview (при светлой теме на телефоне)
[image: Как отображается сайт при включенной темной теме на смартфонах Xiaomi]

Как отображается сайт при включенной темной теме на смартфонах Xiaomi. Белое стало черным и наоборот + поплыла картинка.

Подскажите, может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, в какую сторону копать в этом вопросе?

Comment: По идее надо вот это добавить в стиль: `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогли решить проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо вот это добавить в стиль:

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```